# Undeterministic behavior JpaRepository

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea

I have a piece of code that extends JpaRepository (`List<X> findByY(<Y> y);`). It compiles fine, unit tests calling the function run fine under Maven, Eclipse does not have an issue (unit test and running application), running the unit test in IntelliJ works fine... But if I run the complete application in IntelliJ, I get a big fat exception.

I've tried to debug Spring to see where this is actually going wrong. I'm not enough into Spring to notice where the seemingly non-deterministic behavior is coming from.

One obvious issue I have with the stacktrace is that there seems to be some translation going on. The sentence

```
could not resolve property: ritadministratie of: org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder
```

should read

```
could not resolve property: ritadministratie of: org.ritadministratie.model.ritadministratie.Vervoerder
```

But the real issue is the exception itself.

I also tried to update spring-boot from 2.1.0.RELEASE to 2.1.5.RELEASE but that didn't solve anything.

This is the full stack trace. I'm pretty sure I can't share the full source code. But the code is basic Spring stuff (reading xml files, writing the same class as entity to database).

```
14:29:32.119 [ForkJoinPool-6-worker-3] INFO  org.ritadministratie.conversion.RitadministratieConverter - Exception: 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ritadministratie of: org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder [select generatedAlias0 from org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.ritadministratie=:param0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ritadministratie of: org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder [select generatedAlias0 from org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.ritadministratie=:param0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:373) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.findByRitadministratie(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.ritadministratie.conversion.RitadministratieConverter.convertRitadministratie(RitadministratieConverter.java:95) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.ritadministratie.conversion.RitadministratieConverter.lambda$convertBctcontrole$0(RitadministratieConverter.java:87) [classes/:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) [?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:408) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:736) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:159) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:173) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) [?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:661) [?:?]
    at org.ritadministratie.conversion.RitadministratieConverter.lambda$convertBctcontrole$1(RitadministratieConverter.java:84) [classes/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ritadministratie of: org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder [select generatedAlias0 from org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.ritadministratie=:param0]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3407) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3707) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:217) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:173) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:210) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ritadministratie of: org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder [select generatedAlias0 from org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.ritadministratie=:param0]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3407) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3707) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:217) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:173) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:210) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ritadministratie of: org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml.Vervoerder
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1987) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:515) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1045) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1290) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4706) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4174) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2138) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:815) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:609) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.i... shortened for max length
```

I wonder if people have seen this before. Any help is appreciated.

edit: 
Vervoerder classes:

```
package org.ritadministratie.model.arbeidstijdenxml;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@SuppressWarnings({"squid:S00116"})
@Entity
@Table(name = ArbeidstijdenXml.TABLE_PREFIX + "Vervoerder")
@EqualsAndHashCode
@XmlRootElement(namespace = ArbeidstijdenXml.NAMESPACE, name = "Vervoerder")
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public
class Vervoerder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public Long id;

    @XmlElement(namespace = ArbeidstijdenXml.NAMESPACE)
    public String KvKnr;

    @XmlElement(namespace = ArbeidstijdenXml.NAMESPACE)
    public String Pnr;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Arbeidstijden arbeidstijden;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vervoerder", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @XmlElement(namespace = ArbeidstijdenXml.NAMESPACE)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public List<Ondernemerskaart> Ondernemerskaart;
}
```

and

```
package org.ritadministratie.model.ritadministratiexml;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@SuppressWarnings({"squid:S00116"})
@Entity
@Table(name = RitadministratieXml.TABLE_PREFIX + "Vervoerder")
@EqualsAndHashCode
@XmlType(namespace = RitadministratieXml.NAMESPACE, name = "Vervoerder")
public
class Vervoerder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public Long id;

    @XmlElement(namespace = RitadministratieXml.NAMESPACE)
    public String KvKnr;

    @XmlElement(namespace = RitadministratieXml.NAMESPACE)
    public String Pnr;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vervoerder", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @XmlElement(namespace = RitadministratieXml.NAMESPACE)
    public List<Ondernemerskaart> Ondernemerskaart;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Ritadministratie ritadministratie;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `Vervoerder` class?

Comment: It doesn't translate anything. However apparently you have 2 entities with the same name. You can only have a single entity with the same name. The default name for an entity is the class-name (NOT the FQN, just the classname). Hence one of them wins, your test will only load one of them (or the order is different). If one of them isn't an entity then remove the `@Entity` else give them an explicit name through `@Entity(name="vervoerder") and `@Entity(name="xmlVervoerder")`.

Comment: @M. Deinum: I understand what you are saying. Somehow the code works in other environments. Could you provide some background information/docs/code on your statement?

Comment: The JPA spec is clear about this. Different environments have different loading rules (order of packages, classes etc.). Hence in one environment it might come first, in the other last.

Comment: This did work. I was not able to locate "The JPA spec" that defined this though.